# How to refer to current node name in "execute at begin node"

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I'm wondering how can I reference to current node name in `execute at begin node` property.

```
\node[execute at begin node = \command_which_uses_node_name_to_to_do_soething_draw_uml_component_symbol] (){Node-name};
```

Comment: Could you give a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Meter: That's not an MWE. An MWE is a complete minimal example document, which saves people the work of having to come up with a test document themselves (because that part of answering questions is pretty boring).

Comment: @Meter: Is anything missing from my answer?

Answer (score 14):

The node name is stored in `\tikz@fig@name` at the time the code in `execute at begin node` is executed.

Here's an MWE, which prints `> \tikz@fig@name=macro:
->myname.` into the `.log` file:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    teststyle/.style={
        execute at begin node=\show\tikz@fig@name   
    }
} 
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (myname) [teststyle] {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: even if we know its _future_ name, the node does not yet exist at that time (`execute at begin node`).

Comment: This command fails if the node has no name. Any idea how to get the "identifier" of a node? (If possible matching the "\tikztotarget" name?)