# How to calculate item distance from the top of a schema diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

To make schema diagram

[image]

I use following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape
                      }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart{second}
\underline{ID}\\
name\\
dept\_name\\
salary};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}\\
building\\
budget};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-13pt]$(instructor.east)$) -- ([yshift=1pt]$(department.west)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In line `\draw[->] ([yshift=-13pt]$(instructor.east)$) -- ([yshift=1pt]$(department.west)$);` I make a `yshift`. To do this edit the `yshift` value several time to fit the output with expectation. If I know the distance of each item in the diagram from the top or bottom I can easily make decision for `yshift` value just multiplication item no and distance.

Something like `\draw[->] ([yshift=-((3.5*distance)pt]$(instructor.north)$) -- ([yshift=-(1.5*distance)pt]$(department.north)$);`;

Or,

`\draw[->] ([yshift=-((1.5*distance)pt]$(instructor.south)$) -- ([yshift=-(2.5*distance)pt]$(department.south)$);`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perhaps simplest way is to really make use of the node parts. **UPDATE**: Added the horizontal line. (Unfortunately, Ti*k*Z does not yet accept a list for the option `rectangle split draw splits`, while it does for `rectangle split part fill`, so I had to draw the line by other means.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,alias=nahh,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        rectangle split draw splits=false,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape,
        draw,
        append after command={\pgfextra{\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \draw(\tikzlastnode.text split west) -- (\tikzlastnode.text split  east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        }
        },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape,
                      }}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic,rectangle split parts=5] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart[rectangle split draw splits=false]{second}
\underline{ID}
\nodepart{third}
name
\nodepart{fourth}
dept\_name
\nodepart{five} salary
};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor,rectangle split parts=4] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}
\nodepart{third}
building
\nodepart{fourth}
budget};
\draw[->] (instructor.four east) -- (department.two west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Based on [Ignasi's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426039/121799) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88336/121799). Yields the same output.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,backgrounds}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88336/121799
\newcommand{\GetCurrentNodeName}{\tikz@fig@name}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        rectangle split draw splits=false,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape,
        draw,
        },
    Line/.style={
        path picture={
            \draw (\GetCurrentNodeName.text split west) -- (\GetCurrentNodeName.text split east);
        }
        },  
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape,
                      }
        }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic, rectangle split parts=5, Line] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart[rectangle split draw splits=false]{second}
\underline{ID}
\nodepart{third}
name
\nodepart{fourth}
dept\_name
\nodepart{five} salary
};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor,rectangle split parts=4, Line] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}
\nodepart{third}
building
\nodepart{fourth}
budget};
\draw[->] (instructor.four east) -- (department.two west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Just add the horizontal line under the table name. It seems me better look.

Comment: No problem. I am going to bed as it is mid-night.

Comment: line under header you should draw separately. there (so far) not exist a way to incorporate it in `basic` style

Comment: @Zarko I guess this is one more point on which we disagree. Still not too bad, 2 out of over one hundred ;-) Please see my update, everything is in `basic` style... ;-)

Comment: @marmot, bravo for foreground! i'm glad that we disagree :-). you solve some my old problem where i stuck since due to respect to *percusse* 
 (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/why-fill-covers-append-after-command-elements) i didn't start to search  a solution.  +1 :-) :-) :-). however, i hope that ones will done more native solution. this feature is really missing.

Comment: @Zarko Well, I guess that we agree here? ;-) Anyway, thanks a lot! (I actually have used this trick already before but I don't remember where or if I posted an answer with that.) Anyway, thanks!!! ;-)

Comment: @marmot, of course wee agree. if you will have some spare time please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/how-to-politely-tell-someone-that-his-choice-of-answer-is-poor. i had some problems with them, but i learned a lesson ;-).  on the end all is up to op, what (s)he liked more no matter what I think about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complement to marmot's answer. May be a comment could be enough, but a little bit long.

In this case the line under `instructor` or `department` are drawn with a `path picture` command without `\pgfextra` commands.

It's not possible to use it inside a general style because we need to know `nodes'` name, therefore, a `Line` style has been defined and added to `instructor` and `department` nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,alias=nahh,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        rectangle split draw splits=false,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape,
        draw,
        },
    Line/.style={
        path picture={
            \draw (#1.text split west) -- (#1.text split east);
        }
        },  
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape,
                      }
        }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic, rectangle split parts=5, Line=instructor] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart[rectangle split draw splits=false]{second}
\underline{ID}
\nodepart{third}
name
\nodepart{fourth}
dept\_name
\nodepart{five} salary
};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor,rectangle split parts=4, Line=department] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}
\nodepart{third}
building
\nodepart{fourth}
budget};
\draw[->] (instructor.four east) -- (department.two west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Thank you to one of [percusse's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327270/1952) my previous code can be simplified and define a `basic` style which already includes de `path picture` that draws the line on header.

As in `path picture` we need to know the name of the node, we can include the `name` option in the `basic` style. This way the parameter (node's name) is already known when `path picture` starts.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    basic/.style={
        draw, 
      rectangle split,
      rectangle split parts=2,
      rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
      rectangle split draw splits=false,
      minimum width=2.5cm,
      text width=2cm,
      align=left,
      font=\itshape,
      name=#1,     %<-------- Node's name
      path picture={
            \draw (#1.text split west) -- (#1.text split east);
        }
    },
   Diamond/.style={ 
        diamond, 
      draw, 
      shape aspect=2, 
      inner sep = 2pt,
      text centered,
      fill=blue!10!white,
      font=\itshape,
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%There's no explicit name like in "\node (name) {}"
%Node's name is introduced as a parameter in basic style.
\node[basic=instructor, rectangle split parts=5] {instructor
\nodepart{second}
    \underline{ID}
\nodepart{third}
    name
\nodepart{fourth}
    dept\_name
\nodepart{five} salary
};

\node[basic=department, right=5cm of instructor, rectangle split parts=4] 
{department
\nodepart{second}
    \underline{dept\_name}
\nodepart{third}
    building
\nodepart{fourth}
    budget};

\draw[->] (instructor.four east) -- (department.two west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! +1. The only part I don't understand is why you pass the node name to `Line=...`. Wouldn't it be better to pass some information on where you want to draw the line, e.g. between one and two or between two and three, say?

Comment: @marmot Just because I don't know how to make reference to a certain anchor of current node without knowing node's name. I need to know node's name to say `\draw(instructor.text split west)`.

Comment: @marmot I think the updated answer solve's the problem with node's name.

Comment: I added a simplified version to my answer but will be happy to remove it from there if you want to use it in yours. (I guess the background stuff is also not needed in your answer.)

Comment: @marmot No problem, leave it in yours. You discovered this nice trick. For sure I will use it.

Comment: Well, it was discovered by @Jake. Anyway, I'll refer to him and you if I ever use this again.